# Hit timeout for jpeg callback! using Camera2 api

Tags: android, sockets, android-camera2

I am making an application(targets API level above 23) that uses the Camera2 API. It uses async tasks in which a socket is continuously running and getting commands to shoot images from python server.
After taking 2 to 4 images(depending on device) and sending those images to the server via socket the android application gets into an idle state with this log error `E/RequestThread-0: Hit timeout for jpeg callback!`
I have also attached the code snippet and error logs for more info.

I have seen some answers on stack overflow and github issues but it didn't worked out.

```
public void readyCamera() {

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String pickedCamera = getCamera(manager);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        manager.openCamera(pickedCamera, cameraStateCallback, null);
        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(1920, 1088, ImageFormat.JPEG, 3 /* images buffered */);
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "imageReader created");
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void processImage(Image image) {

    final ByteBuffer buffer;
    final byte[] bytes;


    boolean success = false;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSSSSS", 
Locale.getDefault());
    String currentDateandTime = (sdf.format(new Date()) + "_count-" + 
 QopiusApp.shootCommandCounter);
//        QopiusApp.connection_message = "shooting starts " + 
currentDateandTime;
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
"/Pictures/image" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg");
//        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
"/Pictures/image.jpg");
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    if (image.getFormat() == ImageFormat.JPEG) {
        buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        bytes = new byte[image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().remaining()]; // 
makes byte array large enough to hold image
        buffer.get(bytes); // copies image from buffer to byte array


        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            output.write(bytes);    // write the byte array to file
            success = true;

            // bytes
            if (QopiusApp.command.equalsIgnoreCase("shoot")) {
                new AppExecutors().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
//                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//                    new Thread(new SendImage(bytes)).start();
                        if (socket != null) {
                            BufferedInputStream reader = null;
                            BufferedOutputStream out = null;

                            try {
                                out = new BufferedOutputStream( 
socket.getOutputStream() );
                                reader = new BufferedInputStream( new 
FileInputStream( file ) );

//                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[ 409600 ];
                                int bytesRead;
                                while ( (bytesRead = reader.read(bytes)) 
!= -1 ) {
                                    out.write( bytes, 0, bytesRead );

socket.getOutputStream().write("EndBytes".getBytes());
                                }
//                                    
socket.getOutputStream().write("EndBytes".getBytes());
                                reader.close();
                                out.flush();
//                                    out.close();

                            } catch (UnknownHostException u) {
                                System.out.println(u);
                            } catch (IOException i) {
                                i.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    out.flush();
//                                        out.close();
                                    reader.close();
                                    //socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException i) {
                                    System.out.println(i);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

//                    thread.start();
//                    new Thread(new SendImage(bytes)).start();
                QopiusApp.shootCommandCounter++;

//                    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
//                    output.write(bytes);    // write the byte array to 
file
//                    success = true;
               // QopiusApp.connection_message = "shooting starts " + 
currentDateandTime;
                Log.e("MyPhotoCounter", "shoot " + QopiusApp.shootCommandCounter + " end");

            } else if (QopiusApp.command.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) {
                QopiusApp.shootCommandCounter = 0;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera stopped!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("MyPhotoCounter", "Close command received " + QopiusApp.shootCommandCounter + " ending");
                stopCamera();
            }


        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            image.close(); // close this to free up buffer for otherimages
            Log.e("Image", "Image capture sucessfull111111111111 --------- 
--------->");

        }

    }


}
```

I expect that the camera take the same number of images which it gets from the server(for eg. 10 images) and send those images to the server.

But my application gets into an idle state after taking 2 to 4 images.

For 2 images out of three it goes well.
`2019-11-05 11:38:55.355 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/Response: 
SocketResponse{command='shoot', shootCount=3}
2019-11-05 11:38:55.479 14944-15268/com.qopius.camera_v2 I/RequestThread-0: Received jpeg.
2019-11-05 11:38:55.480 14944-15268/com.qopius.camera_v2 I/RequestThread-0: Producing jpeg buffer...
2019-11-05 11:38:55.482 14944-14944/com.qopius.camera_v2 D/myLog: onImageAvailable
2019-11-05 11:38:55.490 14944-14944/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/MyPhotoCounter: shoot 2 end
2019-11-05 11:38:55.490 14944-14944/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/Image: Image capture sucessfull111111111111 ------------------>
2019-11-05 11:38:55.490 14944-14944/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/MyPhotoCounter: 2`

After this the following error happens:
`2019-11-05 11:38:56.387 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/Socket status ======>: camera open
2019-11-05 11:38:56.388 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 W/SENT: [SocketResponse{command='shoot', shootCount=3}] 5
2019-11-05 11:38:56.388 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 D/Socket: While loop running ...............
2019-11-05 11:38:56.389 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/Socket: 82
2019-11-05 11:38:56.389 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/myLog: onDisConnectedJSON document was not fully consumed.
2019-11-05 11:38:56.390 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/Sever: server disconnectedcom.google.gson.JsonIOException: JSON document was not fully consumed.
2019-11-05 11:38:56.390 14944-15051/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/Async: Socket running!!!
2019-11-05 11:38:56.391 14944-14944/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/myLog: SocketResponse{command='shoot', shootCount=3}
2019-11-05 11:38:56.396 14944-15473/com.qopius.camera_v2 D/Socket: While loop running ...............
2019-11-05 11:38:56.397 14944-15473/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/Socket: 0
2019-11-05 11:38:56.548 14944-15100/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/RequestThread-0: Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
2019-11-05 11:38:56.552 14944-15100/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
2019-11-05 11:38:56.553 14944-15100/com.qopius.camera_v2 I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
2019-11-05 11:38:56.553 14944-15100/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot call idle while in state: 0
2019-11-05 11:38:59.757 14944-15318/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/RequestThread-0: Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
2019-11-05 11:38:59.772 14944-15318/com.qopius.camera_v2 I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
2019-11-05 11:38:59.772 14944-15318/com.qopius.camera_v2 E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot call idle while in state: 0`